# Additional packages marked as "no longer required" after reboot following do-release-upgrade to 22.04 from 21.10

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, plasma, ubuntu-studio

After doing a command-line do-release-upgrade from Ubuntu Studio (Plasma) 21.10 to 22.04, answering 'yes' to all the prompts and rebooting, I did another sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; and saw the following:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  amd64-microcode dvdauthor fonts-adf-gillius fonts-adf-libris fonts-adf-switzera fonts-beteckna gcc-11-base:i386 gnome-accessibility-themes growisofs jamin k3b-i18n libabsl20200923
  libatspi2.0-0:i386 libcodec2-0.9 libconfig9 libdap27 libepoxy0:i386 libepsilon1 libevdev2:i386 libffms2-4 libgeos-3.9.0 libgtk-4-common libgupnp-1.2-0 libk3b7
  libkdecorations2private8 libkf5plotting5 libkf5pulseaudioqt2 libllvm12 libllvm12:i386 libmbedcrypto3 libmd4c0:i386 libnetcdf18 liborcus-0.16-0 liborcus-parser-0.16-0
  libpcre2-16-0:i386 libpoppler111 libproj19 libqhull8.0 librsvg2-2:i386 librtmidi5 libvigraimpex11 libvpx6:i386 libwebp6 libx264-160 libxcb-xinerama0:i386 libyaml-cpp0.6
  materia-gtk-theme odbcinst perl-modules-5.32 plasma-wallpapers-addons python3-altgraph python3-astor python3-easywebdav python3-funcparserlib python3-future python3-gnupg
  python3-ipython-genutils python3-macholib python3-pefile python3-pyelftools python3-rawkit python3-rply python3-simplejson tcl-tls tcllib ttf-unifont
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

Some other packages were already removed as part of the 'do-release-upgrade' so I'm surprised that I wasn't prompted to remove these, and that they remain. I'm hesitant to go ahead with the 'autoremove' because in the past doing that has broken my system. Did something go wrong with the upgrade, or is it safe to go ahead and remove these packages?  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it recommended to remove obsolete packages after a dist upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705229/is-it-recommended-to-remove-obsolete-packages-after-a-dist-upgrade)

Comment: I prefer to remove all unneeded packages, and would hope the release upgrade process would take care of that. I'm concerned because these showed _after_ the major release upgrade, and not during the upgrade when a number of other packages were automatically removed. In particular, the amd-microcode package makes me wonder if the release upgrade fully completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining a number of those packages and seeing that many had more recent versions installed, I decided to explicitly install the *amd64-microcode package* and remove the others via the `sudo apt autoremove` command.

To get a reasonable aesthetic after the upgrade I had to also explicitly install ubuntustudio-wallpapers-jammy and apply some Ubuntu Studio themes and styles manually. To get my pre-upgrade Firefox saved passwords and profile back I had to rename `~/snap/firefox` and restart the browser.

After doing these things, I've had no further problems so far. I'm still curious why the do-release-upgrade didn't take care of these for me, but my main question is resolved.